# Different Central Tendency Measures for Describing Groups or Individuals

Tags: clustering, data-mining, mean, median

**Background:** I have records with various metrics for many users. I want to develop a profile for each and also group similar users using clustering.

**Question:** When developing a profile for each user, would it be incorrect to use a different central tendency measure for each user metric depending on the symmetry of that particular user's data? For example, Metric0 might be symmetric for User0 (mean) but not User2 (median) even though Metric0 across all users is heavily skewed (median). Does that matter in a situation where I'm creating profiles for each user?

Generic example of results:

```
User  Measure0  Metric0  Measure1  Metric1  ....
U0    Mean      2.123    Median    172040
U1    Mean      2.653    Median    201340
U2    Median    2.569    Mean      172940
U3    Mean      2.118    Mean      171300

...
```

Also, will the above impact how I perform or interpret clustering techniques on the users to determine similar profiles?

Comment: It may or mat not impact the result. If your distributions are nice and smooth, there will be little difference between the mean and median. I suggest to not mix different statistics. If you have too many anomalies why not **always use the median**.

Comment: I agree with always using the median. I couldn't find any questions similar to mine about mixing different statistics. Intuitively, it seems wrong but given it was per user I thought it would be best to provide the best statistic for each user. That was my thought process.